# Ruby Dir.mkdir No such file or directory @ dir_s_mkdir

Tags: ruby

I have a script that calls Dir.mkdir nesting a folder in /process_data

```
path = "d:/process_data/#{processName}"
Dir.mkdir path
```

Unfortunately it fails 70% of the time.

The base directory exists and is successfully being populated by other processes.

Any thoughts on why this would be happening?

Update: Having googled a bit more someone suggested the solution of using `FileUtils.mkdir_p`. I don't think it's the right approach to resolving this but it'll do for now, it's worked so far.

Would still appreciate and ideas on this.

Thanks.

Comment: `path = "'d:/process_data/#{processName}'"` should probably work.

Comment: @SOliver It might be happening because one of the parent directories to the path you are trying to create is absent. Does the process_data directory already exist? Also, it might be that `process_name` contains '/' which would be treated as further nesting. `mkdir_p` will work in that case as it will create all the parent directories as well.

Comment: @erosenin the parent directory definitely exists, the processor itself manages to use it at least 30% of the time. The process_name is a unique numbers only string.